# For all x, x is not an element of a set A\B. what does the figure look like?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For all x, x is not an element of a set A\B. what does the figure look like?

I mean, when x is an element of a set A\B,

the figure looks like [Fig.1.8](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter1/1_2_2_set_operations.php) from that webpage.

**The shaded area shows the set A−B.**

But `x is not an element of a set A\B` is equivalent to `If x is in Set A then x is in Set B`.

It seems look like set A is a subset of set B.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to look at this is from a definition of set difference: that being

$$A \setminus B = A \cap B^c = \left\{ x \mid x \in A \text{ and } x \not \in B\right\}$$

Then $x\not \in A \setminus B$ means that "$x \in A$ and $x \not \in B$" must not be true. This requires the use of the logical negation: if we want to negate "$P$ and $Q$", we have "either not $P$, or not $Q$." Thus, the negation of

$$x \in A \text{ and } x \not \in B$$

is the statement

$$x \not \in A \text{ or } x \in B$$

Thus, $x \not \in A \setminus B$ means "$x \not \in A$ but $x \in B$."

---

Another way is from the algebra of sets and set operations. We use the following:

- That $A \setminus B$ can be defined as $A \cap B^c$
- That $x \not \in S$ for some set $S$ means $x \in S^c$ (a definition of complement)
- One of De Morgan's laws: $(S \cap T)^c = S^c \cup T^c$
- That $x \in S \cup T$ means $x \in S$ or $x \in T$

Then we have
\begin{align*}
x \not \in A \setminus B
&\iff x \in (A \setminus B)^c\\
&\iff x \in (A \cap B^c)^c\\
&\iff x \in A^c \cup B^{c^c}\\
&\iff x \in A^c \cup B\\
&\iff x \in A^c \text{ or } x \in B\\
&\iff x \not \in A \text{ or } x \in B
\end{align*}

---

Of course, we can look at this using a Venn diagram too. Pictorially, below, the set of elements $x$ that are in $A \setminus B$ are in the blue region.

[image]

Note then that if $x \not \in A \setminus B$, then it is in the pink region. This means it can be in $B$, it can be in both $A$ and $B$, or it can be in neither of them. All of these is good, so long as $x$ is not in $A$.

This the clearest interpretation of the statement "$x \not \in A$ or $x \in B$,", then, if the logical nature of everything else is still bugging you:

*"Let $x \not \in A \setminus B$. Then if $x \in A$, then $x$ must be in $B$. (That is, $x \in A \implies x \in A \cap B$.) Otherwise, i.e. if $x \not \in A$, then we're good."*

---

In short, you are correct, partly, but your interpretation is shortsighted in the sense that $x$ need not be in $A$ or $B$ to begin with. In particular, no restriction at all need be placed on whether $A$ is a subset of $B$, or vice versa.

Comment: Your explanation in detail sheds light on these expression. Appreciate it.