# Verification of proof for very simple set theory statement

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I have been attempting to prove the following simple statement:

$A \cap B^c=\emptyset \implies A\subset B$

where $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary sets.

**Proof attempt:**

Let $A$ and $B$ be arbitrary sets and let $A \cap B^c=\emptyset$. Because $A \cap B^c=\emptyset$, $x\notin A \cap B^c$ for all $x$ in the universe.

In turn, $x\in A^c$ or $x\in B$.

Let $x\in A$; because $x\in A$, $x\notin A^c$; as a result, (because either $x\in A^c$ or $x\in B$) $x\in B$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: How do you get “$x\in A^c $ or $x\in B$“?

Comment: Also, your statement “$x\notin A\cap B^c$  for all x in the universe” could be better phrased as “$ \nexists x$ such that $x\in A\cap B^c$”.

Comment: @insipidintegrator DeMorgan's law

Comment: @insipidintegrator Great; thank you for the feedback.

Comment: I believe there is a wrong usage of De Morgan’s Laws. The beginning statement is “$x\notin (A\cap B^c)$”, and NOT, 
    “($x\notin A) \wedge (x\notin B^c$)”. Hope this helps

Comment: I used DeMorgan's Law on $\neg(x\in A \land x\in B^c)$, which is the same as $x\notin A \cap B^c$.

Comment: $P:\lnot (x\in A\land x\in B^c)$ is not logically equivalent to $Q:x\notin A\cap B^c$. P implies Q, but Q does not imply P.

Comment: Why not? Is $P$ not equivalent to $Q$ by the definition of set membership?

Comment: $x\notin A\cap B^c$ and $x \in A\cap B$ may hold simultaneously. Just draw a Venn Diagram. Thus here Q is being satisfied but not P.

Comment: Why is $P$ not satisfied? Could you be more specific?

Comment: For example, does the answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4086350/1063927 not use the fact that $P$ is equivalent to $Q$ (under certain assumptions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rephrasing:

Let $A, B$ non empty subsets of $X$;

We have $B \cup B^c = X$;

$ A \subset B \cup B^c;$

If $ x \in A$ then $x \in B$ or $B^c$;

Since $A \cap B^c =\emptyset$ we have
$x \in B$, and we are done.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, note that $B^c$ is a bit scary. It needs some, implicit or explicit, set $U$ that contains everthing you're talking about, so that $B^c$ really means $U \setminus B$. In this case, though, that doesn't affect the argument.

Your argument is correct, although one could say that using De Morgan to go from $x \not\in A \cap B^c$ to $x \in A^c$ or $x \in B$ is already more complicated than needed.

More direct is the following.

Take $x \in A$. Because $A \cap B^c = \emptyset$, that implies that $x \not \in B^c$. Therefore, $x \in B$.